# Redactor Images Button Missing

Tags: redactor, wysiwyg

I am currently using the Standard JSON configuration. My config is below. I cannot get the image button to show up for my Body Field/Rich Text. This is the same configuration I've used on other CraftCMS sites without issue.

```
{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen','video'],
    toolbarFixed: true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure if it matters but in my config I have buttons in quotes

```
"buttons": ["format","bold","italic","underline","lists","link","file","image","horizontalrule"],
```

Comment: Double quotes are the standard for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this setting:
`imageUpload: true`

Example:

```js
    $('.editor').redactor({
        s3: 's3upload.php',
        fileUpload: true,
        imageUpload: true,

        buttons: ['format', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'deleted',
                  'lists', 'outdent', 'indent',
                  'image', 'file', 'link', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule', 'source'],

        "plugins":["source"],
    });
```