# Redactor image button not showing up

Tags: craft3, redactor

I have seen a few questions the same as this, but none with answers that work. I am trying to use redactor to allow for dynamic blog posts to be written by my team. In my redactor set up file I have:

```
buttons: ['html', 'format', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', 'lists', 'image', 'file', 'link'],
```

AND

imageUpload: true

And yet, the button does not show up when I go into my editor.

Any ideas about what else it could be?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you need to select the redactor config on your field's settings...

Example - say you edited `config/redactor/Standard.json`

Go into your admin panel, then go to Settings, then Fields.

Open one of your redactor, and scroll down to where you select the field type. When you select Redactor, you get a new option underneath.

And you then select which Redactor Config you want to use.

[image: Select Redactor Config after choosing the field type]

If you're not seeing it, maybe try clearing your caches. And then double-check that you've saved your redactor config in the right place, and it's got the right file permissions.

Comment: This was exactly it. I didn't even have to edit the files, though I'm glad I know where they live now. I just chose Standard and it already included the photo button. Thank you!

Comment: Great! You're not the first, and won't be the last, to run into this. (I miss it regularly). Mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Failing that, you may have to use double-quotes in your config file, rather than single quotes - [as shown on the github page](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor#redactor-configs).

It doesn't explicitly say you have to use double-quotes, but I think I ran into this before.

[See also this guy's question.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/redactor-images-button-missing)